# Adding/Updating/Deleting Exchange Calendar entries externally?

Tags: .net, exchange-server

I'm trying to see how it would be possible to externally maintain a user's (or users') Outlook calendar using .NET.  We use a CRM for various sales and account management appointments, and now they need a seamless way of integrating the CRM events with the Outlook events.  Is Exchange writable via web services or would this need to be done via some SQL-like functionality?

Probably a pretty basic question, I'm just trying to find some starting points on how feasible this would be to write before some manager here decides to buy yet another third party product that is beyond bloated...that I then have to code on top of because it doesn't work "quite" how they wanted it.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `System.Web.Mail` namespace to access the users calendar provided you are using integrated security.

There is an MS Exchange API that you could use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637749%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx

Finally MS Exchange has an SDK http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/default.aspx

Comment: Integrated security would be a problem in that I'm thinking this should be some single app that runs for a subset of users which manages their calendars behind the scenes.  I'll take a look at that API, thanks.